# Getting url from file location using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a slider that uses an html file in a frame on SharePoint.  Slides are changed quite frequently and this slider is being rolled out 10 more times.  I am wanting to create a workflow so the end user can change the slider/href themselves.  I have created the function below which dynamically creates my "li" and "a" and is working.  Eventually I will use variables to get the "src" etc.

*My question is I would like to do a "for each" to run through a specified directory and grab the file names so I can create a new "li" and "a" for each file and pull in my "src" for the "a" dynamically also.*

If I did not say this correctly I apologize.  I am a newbie to JavaScript and programming in general.  I have spent quite a bit of time trying to figure this out myself.  Any assistance/explanation/direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
        document.body.onload = addElement;

        function addElement() {
            //run through a directory and grab URLs

            // create a new li element 
            var newLi = document.createElement("li");
            //create img
            var newImg = document.createElement("img");
            newImg.setAttribute("src", "Intranet_643x296.jpg");
            newImg.setAttribute("height", "100%");
            newImg.setAttribute("border-radius", "10px");
            newImg.setAttribute("alt", "Einstein");
            // Set its contents:
            document.getElementById("ulimage").appendChild(newImg);
        }
    </script>
    <ul id="ulimage"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your question is a statement. my question is, my name is robert.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I think although not obvious, his question is pretty obvious.

Comment: one can obviously sawp "i would like to" with "how do i" but even then the question is unclear. hopefully someone else understood it.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible !
you can't access client filesystem for obvious security reason.

Comment: sure you can. that's what file inputs are for.

Comment: you can't access a whole directory via "file" inputs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on the client side unfortunately as @erwan has answered, it isn't possible.

Also, I assume the directory is on the server?
If so then just get all the filenames server side and then you can use them in your javascript.

---

UPDATE

If you are using php then something like this will grab everything in a specific directory

```
// Directory 
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images';

chdir($directory); // change directory (not necessary but retrieves only filenames) 

// Get all files in directory
$images = glob('*'); // returns an array that you can use in a foreach loop

// also you should probably lookup the glob function (see below) to see the options
```

See documentation for glob here [Glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)
If you want to only select specific extentions then use a pattern

```
glob('*.{jpg, png}', GLOB_BRACE)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It is on the server side.  Is there a way to dynamically grab all of them on the server side?  They are changed a couple of times a week and I was hoping to have it automated so I would not have to do it for each site.  No more than 7-8 slides at one time.

Comment: what language are you using? php?

Comment: Our corporate office will not enable support for PHP on our farm.  Its not clean enough for me to set up a PHP server and have SharePoint serve up the content in a frame.  Any other suggestions or solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately you need a server side language to be able to access the file system. HTML and JavaScript won't be able to achieve what you are looking for